# How many times has Shoaib Akhtar bowled 160 kmph or faster?

Tags: cricket, trivia

How many times has Shoaib Akhtar bowled faster than 160 kmph?

During the England vs Pakistan match in the 2003 World Cup, he delivered at the speed of 161.3kmph. Is this the only occasion?

Answers providing records of domestic matches are also welcome.

Comment: For a moment, I thought we were talking about lawn bowling or ten-pin bowling, and I enjoyed the mental visuals of 160kmph bowling in either of those sports. :)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I am not sure whether I should approve your edit because I have tagged cricket already and any cricket fan would at least know Akhtar's name. I leave that upon the mods :)

Comment: No problem at all.  If you include the sport in the title, your question will perform better in search engine results, thus making it easier for others to find. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per official records that is only time he has crossed the 100 mile per hour mark (which is 161kmph), Brett Lee and Shaun Tait being the only other cricketers to do so.

In local or other tournaments weren’t recorded with that detail while Aktar was playing. I don’t know with certainty that this is the only time he ever reached that mark in his career. On the other hand this is the only time he crossed it in international stage.

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the "official records" you are referring to here?